# Allocate a struct from an existing file descriptor - c

Tags: c, shared-memory

I'm creating a server and a client that are both accessing shared memory and changing the data in the shared memory.

I've used `shm_open` to open the shared memory, `ftruncate` to change the size of the shared memory, and `mmap` to map the shared memory object of type struct.

I want to create a function that accesses the shared memory via a file descriptor and returns a pointer to the struct.

For example:

```
XStruct * accessMem(int fd){ /*what to do here? */};
```

I'm not sure how to go about this, or what functions to use in order to access the shared memory. Any help would be great.

**This is homework, so an explanation would be very helpful.**

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that kind of what [`mmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) does? So your `accessMem` function simply calls `mmap` and returns the pointer `mmap` returns.

Comment: I think what he means is that he has already done the mmap, now needs to cut some chunk out of the shared memory and return it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah what Ajay Brahmakshatriya said is what I'd like the function to do. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use (or implement a memory allocator to act on the block you received from mmap).

One simple implementation could be to use a bump allocator.

Store the value of the pointer you received from mmap. Every time you need to allocate memory for a struct, increment the pointer by sizeof (struct) and return the original pointer.

```
void *allocator_top; // Define a global pointer to top of the "heap" area.
.
.
.
allocator_top = mmap(...); // Do this wherever you perform the mmap
.
.

Xstruct * accessMem(){
    void *temp = allocator_top;
    // Need to check here if you have exceeded the amount of space mapped. If yes, you need to expand and add more pages.
    allocator_top += sizeof(Xstruct);
    return temp;
}
```

Edit : If you have multiple shared regions and want to allocate from them separately, you can take a void **allocator_top as an argument to accessMem() and pass the top of the region you want to allocate from.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The homework question states that the function passed a file descriptor, and I don't think I can actually change this. Do you know of anyway this would apply to accessing shared memory? I think the homework question is quite vague/ ambiguous for this particular section.

Comment: If that is the requirement, you need to just map more memory every time `accessMemory(int fd)` is called by calling mmap and returning the return value you get from mmap. Though this will lead to a lot of internal fragmentation since you can only map multiples of PAGE_SIZE in call to mmap.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help! I'll see what I can do with that information.